# How do I compile for ONLY 32 bit for Mac OSX with Xcode 9.4?

Tags: xcode, 32-bit

I have a very old macOS project that I will be porting and converting to 64 bit but for now I need to compile and debug it in 32 bit mode because it has a complex module that will only run in 32 bit mode. I have a Mojave system set up with Xcode 9.4 and can successfully compile everything 32 bit in Terminal with my personal make scheme. However, when I try to throw a test app into Xcode to debug, compilation fails at the link stage. Xcode ignores my libraries because it insists on building 64 bit and then fails on undefined symbols that reside in them. Yep, they are all 32 bit as that's what I need right now.

So stupid question. How do I configure Xcode 9.4 to stop trying to compile 64 bit and only compile 32 bit ? I am brand new to it. It looks like I have all of my compile flags set properly and I have the macOS Deployment Target set to macOS 10.13.

I can set that target all the way down to macOS 10.6 and the same problem still persists.

What's the trick here gang? Do I need to go with an even older version of Xcode?

I tried to remove "x86_64" from Valid Architectures, leaving only "i386" but doing this causes Xcode to immediately crash with a SIGABRT the very instant that I hit the compile button !

Messing around with the "Architectures" setting causes Xcode to crash as well. There isn't a 32 bit only option available there, BTW.

Comment: what kind of device still runs in 32-bit architecture? old iPhones? or old Macs?

Comment: I have a Mac running Mojave set up for this operation. I do not intend to stick with 32bit but I need it now to walk through some old 32bit only code.  My question simply is: How do I configure this XCode beast to compile AND link a 32 bit project ? Supposedly 9.4 is the last version capable of building 32 bit executables. But it chokes when I attempt to suppress x86_64 arch flags.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9.4/9.4.1 is supposed to be the last version able to build 32 bit apps. Well, it’s NOT. It fails miserably.

I rolled back to Xcode 9.2 and it works perfectly.

So, official reports of Xcode v9.4 as the last 32 bit project builder are incorrect.

If you need to compile and debug old 32 bit code, go with v9.2.

Actually, v9.3.1 works too.

Just stay away from 9.4+ if you need to compile and link 32 bit binaries

Comment: Ah, just happened upon this old post of mine and wanted to clear up this very bad info provided by me, sorry. 32 bit compilations work just fine on Xcode 9.4+. You just need to know what flags to supply and it's simply the same exact ones used to compile 32 bit binaries from previous versions of Xcode. It's just that Apple no longer provides them for easy picking by the time you get to 9.4 because they are steering you hard toward 64 bit.